# OT: Community Wiki or Blog Post request

Tags: discussion, off-topic, community-wiki, super-contest

I was wondering if SU would support the idea of having a case modding contest of some type, NOT for reputation points, but for sheer SnG.

Comment: Any specific ideas of how such a contest would look like? What do you mean by "Community Wiki"? I don't see how a Community Wiki Q&A about case modding contests would fit our scope in any way – this is simply *not constructive*. A blog entry, probably a better idea. If you have more concrete details and arguments, that'd make it easier for others to vote ;)

Comment: I think it would be a better choice for the blog indeed

Comment: I was just wanting a place for people to post their case mods or special work they've done in towers, t'is all. For a blog, could people post their pictures?

Comment: Sounds like a bloggerific idea to me! If you make a proposal, we'll look over it.

Comment: Do I need to write the entire thing out? Or just a rough idea of what to put in there, and ask the community for more content to add?

Comment: Just an idea would be a start!

Comment: @Luke Ivo and I like the idea, so you don't need to have people vote. Write up a proposal telling us a) what sort of contest you want to run, b) how it would work, c) what the prizes might look like, and d) any other details we'd need to run the contest. Post it on meta or email it to me and Ivo. Then we'll go from there. We'll probably put this off a bit, since there are [other contest-ish things we might need to think about soon](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) but it's a neat idea and I'd like to see it happen eventually.

Comment: @nhinkle Do I correctly remember Ivo saying there were some funds left for computer hardware and stuff?

Comment: @slhck we have some funds left, yes. And we could probably get more if we ask nicely and it's a well-organized thing. If Luke writes us a proposal, we can take it to CHAOS/the community team and try to get official backing for it.

Comment: @nhinkle That would be awesome! I'm going out camping this weekend, but I'll write up something for Monday orTuesday. Thanks for the encouragement

Comment: @Luke again, no rush. This is more of a 6-8 _months_ than a 6-8 weeks thing. Let us know if you need any help?

Comment: People still mod their cases?  How 2005! :)

Comment: @techie007 Or just good cable management? Water cooling? Anything cool inside the physical computer lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VOTE HERE: Yes, this would be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

VOTE HERE: No, this is not a good idea